# Swift Code Error: Value of type String has no member Int

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm trying to build a simple calculator in Swift but i can't figure how or why i'm getting the error ("Value of type String has no member type Int") or how to fix it. This is my code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var isTypingNumber = false
    var firstNumber = Int!()
    var secondNumber = Int!()
    var operation = ""

@IBOutlet weak var calculatorDisplay: UILabel!


@IBAction func acButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

}
@IBAction func number7Tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let number7 = sender.currentTitle
    if isTypingNumber{
        calculatorDisplay.text = calculatorDisplay.text! + number7!!
    }else{
        calculatorDisplay.text = number7
        isTypingNumber = true
    }
}
@IBAction func divideTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    isTypingNumber = false

    firstNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.Int()! **//Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'Int'**
    operation = sender.currentTitle!!
}

@IBAction func equalsTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    isTypingNumber = false
    var result = 0
    secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.Int()! **//Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'Int'**

    if operation == "+" {
        result = firstNumber + secondNumber
    } else if operation == "-" {
        result = firstNumber - secondNumber
    }else if operation == "X" {
        result = firstNumber * secondNumber
    }else if operation == "÷"{
        result = firstNumber / secondNumber
}
    calculatorDisplay.text = "\(result)"
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstNumber = 0
    secondNumber = 0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Don't abuse the force unwrap operator (`!`) like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
firstNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.Int()!
```

You want something like:

```
if let text = calculatorDisplay.text? {
    firstNumber = Int(text)!
}
```

Or if you want to live on the edge:

```
firstNumber = Int(calculatorDisplay.text!)!
```

Comment: Since you are learning Swift, I would encourage you to write all your code without using `!` at all (learn about `if let`, `guard let`, and optional chaining instead).

Comment: Or `calculatorDisplay.text.flatMap{Int($0)}` if you want to get swanky

Comment: @originaluser2 ... don't give them ideas... :p

Comment: @AMomchilov There isn't a single bit of code that isn't made more awesome by functional programming :P

Comment: @originaluser2 Perhaps, until you open a profiler or care about readability (which is significantly hindered, in this case).

Comment: @AMomchilov True, although I'm not sure performance is real concern here. As for readability, I actually like the syntax... although it's certainly not beginner friendly. Another nice thing is that it doesn't introduce new intermediate variables that you may not need (although if you do, `if let` or `guard let` is definitely preferred).

Comment: It can introduce reader uncertainty in the edge cases, making them have to look up docs. How does flatmap handle being called on nil? How will it handle if the initializer fails?

Comment: @AMomchilov I agree, which I why I noted that it wasn't particularly beginner friendly (I only mentioned it in the first place for the sake of showing just how many safe ways there are of dealing with optionals in Swift). Although that being said, you can alt-click on `flatMap` and Xcode will tell you exactly what it does in this context – the same can't be said for `if let`.

Comment: @originaluser2 fair, it'd be cool to have inline docs for language features like `if let`

Answer (score 4):

There is no `Int()` method in the `String` type.

To convert an `Int` to `String`, try this:

```
guard let text = calculatorDisplay.text else {
    //the CalculatorDisplay has no text, deal with it accordingly
}
guard let firstNumber = Int(text) else {
    //the CalculatorDisplay has text, but it's not a valid Int
}

//use firstNumber
```